# Large Canvas/Bitmap in Scrollview or redraw Canvas on scroll? What way is faster and also avoids java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, out-of-memory

I've the known problem that my bitmap/canvas is too big and it throws the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.
My question is what would be the best for my needs.
The Canvas should draw a graph (with given points) and can be very wide (like 3000px and more, theoretically it's wide could be much more, like 20000px). The height is fix.
Because thats to wide for any screen I put it in a Scrollview and draw the whole graph into the canvas.
So thats to wide for the bitmap and I get the error.
The second possibility would be a fix sized canvas where I'd write a "onScroll" method that redraws the graph depending on the users swipe. So it'd only draw a part of the graph.
Would that be the better way or is there a way to make the first option work?
Anyhow please give me some hints and example code for the solution.

Here is the code:

```
Bitmap bitmap  = Bitmap.createBitmap(speedCanvasWidth,speedCanvasHeight,Bitmap.Config.RGB_565); //I also tried ARGB_8888
speedCanvas    = new Canvas(bitmap);
graph.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this with a `BitmapRegionDecoder`.  Just create an instance of one that points to your image.  The system will maintain a handle on the image and then you can call `decode` on the decoder based on what rectangle you want to be displayed within the canvas.  Updates to the canvas will have to be handled based on your needs.  This will help prevent loading this large image that you have to handle.

You can further get details of the Bitmap in question by checking the Bitmap information.  This can be done by loading the bitmap into memory with `BitmapFactory.Options` flags set for to true for `inJustDecodeBounds`.  That keeps the Bitmap from actually being loaded into memory during the checks.

For instance, a quick retrieval could be done with the following:

```
BitmapRegionDecoder decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance("pathToFile", true);
Bitmap regionOfInterestBitmap = decoder.decodeRegion(rectWithinImage, null);//Or with options you have decided to load.
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't have an image. I'm drawing a graph "live" on the canvas. So with this solution I'd have to create the canvas(a very wide one), draw the whole graph on the canvas and then use your solution to load a part of the canvas into the bitmap? If so it would be a good idea. Some short hints how to do that?

Comment: @Hömafreak Oh.  That's a little different.  The whole point to the solution that I was trying to depict was to prevent loading unnecessary pixels into memory based on imagery that you already have control of.  If you load it all at once onto the canvas you will run out of memory creating them with sizes that you want.  There isn't enough available memory on mobile systems to load very large imagery all at once.

Comment: Ok, I also thought about that. So the better solution would be the second possibility that I mentioned?